# How characters can be inserted to strings belonging to a column resulting from an intput command using awk and sed

Tags: linux, command-line, sed, awk

Here is a formula that has appropriate foundation for my purpose – among others it prints files only, using for sizes **powers of** 1024, **2^10** –. Involved file's size is 1382 bytes (1,35 **KiB**):

```
# ls -lh | grep -v '^d' | sed -n '2p' | awk '{print $5, $(NF)}'
1,4K anaconda-ks.cfg
```

Conditions to **apply** in formula:

- insert ' ' **before** the **last** character belonging to the first **column** of the output;
- insert '*iB*' **after** the **last** character belonging to the first **column** of the output;
- **two fractional digits** to the **nearest value** (e.g. 1,095 = 1,09, 1,096 = 1,10);
- print columns related to sizes and files.

Output to **achieve** once conditions applied:

```
# ls -lh | grep -v '^d' | sed <expression> | awk <expression>
1,35 KiB anaconda-ks.cfg
```

Comment: Please explain what results you want and what results you currently get.  It would also be helpful to explain why you are doing this at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should [avoid parsing the ouput of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Instead use the `stat` command.

And instead of trying to forge a new number format, use the command `numfmt` from the coreutils.

So you could use this:

```
for i in *; do 
  printf "%s %s\n" $(stat -c %s "$i" | numfmt --to=iec-i --suffix=B --format "%.2f") "$i"
done
```